How to get the Not sent data for a specific Email sent via Journey Builder
I wanted to extract the bounces and the Not Sent emails sent from the journey every time the journey runs.
I can get the bounce data form the Data view and extract the Not sent via tracking extract but how can I filter the emails related to the specific journey in the not sent extract?

I would recommend you take a look at the NotSent extract first to see what you are having:
So, we have SendID (or JobID) to link with the _Job data view. From there, you can get the email name.
Also from the _Job data view we can link with the _JourneyActivity data view through TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID.
Then we can leverage it to link with the _Journey data view where we can get the journey name.
Sum them up, here is the SQL query I wrote to find the above information:
SELECT
a.SendID,
a.SubscriberKey,
a.EmailAddress,
a.EventDate,
job.EmailName,
journey.JourneyName,
journey.VersionNumber,
a.TriggeredSendExternalKey,
a.Reason
FROM
[Your NotSent extract DE] AS a
INNER JOIN _Job AS job
ON a.SendID = job.JobID
INNER JOIN _JourneyActivity AS journeyActivity
ON  job.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID = journeyActivity.JourneyActivityObjectID
INNER JOIN _Journey AS journey
ON journeyActivity.VersionID = journey.VersionID
WHERE
a.TriggeredSendExternalKey != ''


If you want to filter out by a specific email or a specific journey name, just add these conditions at WHERE clause

Thanks @Duc Le that helps!
